# Python Taking information from a Counter to a file

Tags: python, file, counter

I have a file full of sentences and I want to do a unigram with that:

This is my code and is only getting one letter and I want it to get the word

```
old_lines = open("f.final",'r').readlines() 
new_lines = []

for line in old_lines:
    words = line.split()
    new_lines.append(words)

print new_lines

for lines in new_lines:
    c = Counter(str(lines))


with open("final.final", 'w') as f:
    for k,v in  c.items():
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(k,v))
```

Comment: In this line: `c = Counter(str(lines))` you keep overriding the counter - which will leave you with the last line only...

Answer (score 1):

You're building the counter from a string (i.e. `str(lines)`), which takes the count for each character in the string. You should build the counter directly from the list. And this should be done for all the lines, not just the last line:

```
with open("f.final") as f, open("final.final", 'w') as out_f:
    # take count of all words from all lines
    c = Counter(word for line in f for word in line.strip().split())

    # write to output file
    for k, v in  c.items():
        out_f.write("{} {}\n".format(k,v))
```

Comment: And if I want to do a bigram, trigram and so on?

Comment: @user8865346 Then you'll use nltk. The code you've shown only attempted unigrams, so my answer only addresses that.

Comment: `code` old_lines = open("f.final",'r').readlines() 
new_lines = []
lines =''"

for line in old_lines:
    lines = lines + line
    print lines

token = nltk.word_tokenize(lines)
bigrams = ngrams(token,2)

print Counter(bigrams)

f = open("f2.final",'w')
f.write('what here?') 
`code`
I had this but I have the same problem I cann't take it from the counter to a file. It prints out the bigram correctly but then I don't know what to do

Comment: @user8865346 You should consider posting this as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).